# How to create universal function for insert in database oci

Tags: php, oci8

I create universal function for insert in Oracle database but is not working correctly.

```
function Insert($conn,$sqlText,$arrayInput){
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $stid = oci_parse($conn,$sqlText);

     //   echo '<pre>' . print_r($arrayVariables, true) . '</pre>';
    foreach($arrayInput as $key=>$var)
    {
        // echo 'varable='.$key.'<br/>'.'value='.$var.'</br>';
        oci_bind_by_name($stid,$key,$var);
    }
    oci_execute($stid);

    oci_commit($conn);
    oci_free_statement($stid);
    oci_close($conn);   
}
```

Any idea why is not working?
 I cant find way to see what is sending to oracle by executing oci_execute($stid);. or what is binded

Comment: Any error in oracle log?

Comment: _not working_ Exactly how is it not working?

Comment: No i did not find any errors in alert log or listner log.However 
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01722: invalid number in /var/www/html/tutorial/functions/Normalization.php on line 22 is occur when I execute one insert with more than one parameter

Comment: $conn=oci_connect('papa', 'papa', 'tst');
   $sqlText='insert into TU_CONTEN(tu_title,tu_text,tu_position,topic_id) values (:title,:text,:position,(select tu_id from PAPA.TU_TOPIC where topic=:topic))';
   $arrayInput1[":title"]=$Title;
   $arrayInput1[":text"]=$TextEntry;
   $arrayInput1[":position"]=$maxPosition;
   $arrayInput1[":topic"]=$_SESSION['topic'];
   Insert($conn, $sqlText, $arrayInput1);  -- this one is not working

Comment: I create function again

Comment: function Insert($sql,$paramArray)
{
    $conn = oci_connect('papa', 'papa', 'TST');
    if (!$conn) {
        $m = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
     }
     $stid = oci_parse($conn,$sql);
     foreach($paramArray as $key=>$var)
     {
         oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $var);
         echo 'key= '.$key.'  var= '.$var.'<br/>';
     }
     oci_execute($stid);
}

Comment: see output                                                                                                            
key= :title var= title
key= :topic_id var= topic
key= :text_position var= text_position
key= :text var= text

Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01722: invalid number in /var/www/html/tutorials/Variable/functions.php on line 16

Comment: Name          Null Type           
------------- ---- -------------- 
ID                 NUMBER(38)     
TITLE              VARCHAR2(4000) 
TOPIC_ID           NUMBER(38)     
TEXT_POSITION      NUMBER(38)     
TEXT               VARCHAR2(4000)

Comment: function Insert($sql,$paramArray)
{
    $conn = oci_connect('papa', 'papa', 'TST');
    if (!$conn) {
        $m = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
     }
     $stid = oci_parse($conn,$sql);
     foreach($paramArray as $key=>$var)
     {
         if(is_numeric($var))
         {
             $var1=(int)$var;
             oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $var1);
             var_dump($var1);
         }
        else {
         oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $var);
         var_dump($var);
        }
       
     }
     oci_execute($stid);
}

Comment: This solve issue no idea why $var was always string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically values of array are always string even if I add it as int. So I add check for is_number which solve issue. Thanks for all which try to help me if somebody know why array did not keep int values will be great to share.